# php preg_split how to split by hr

Tags: php, preg-split

I want to split some text using php preg_split by strings like:

```
<hr style="text-align: justify;"> or
<hr>  or
<hr style="other style here">
```

for example text like: `"text 1<hr>text 2<hr style="other style here">text 3`
should give me:

```
array 
[0] text 1
[1] text 2
[2] text 3
```

trying to figur out the regular expressions but it is too difficult for me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just search for `<hr` and then search until you see a `>`:

```
$arr = preg_split('/<hr[^>]*>/', $str);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y9Jics)

Normally I would suggest to use a DOM parser, but for these isolated cases regular expressions do the job just as well.

Comment: I was close... was doing something like : '/<hr[*.]*>/' but it didnt work. thanks for help

Comment: Or, if you want to limit matches to only hr tags without attributes and those with style attributes, `$arr = preg_split('/<hr(?: style=".*")?>/', $str);`

Comment: @eyecatchUp I'm not sure how that would be useful in this case :)

Comment: @Jack Well, actually I just wanted to answer the question. But since you were a few seconds faster and you answer is somewhat more correct, I just left it as a comment. In what cases this might be useful? Well, maybe on some sting like `$str = 'a text that contains "<hr" (for whatever reason) would match until next > occurs<hr>text 2<hr style="other style here">text 3';` ;-)